# Session does not work if higher .net version asp page is loaded in iframe of lower version page

Tags: c#, asp.net, session

I have two different website hosted in IIS. 
1) website A - ASP.NET 2.0 - APP pool A
2) website B - ASP.NET 4.0 - APP pool B

And we have one navigation page in webiste A and each of the page to which it navigates are the pages belonging to webiste B. So these pages gets loaded in an IFrame of navigation page of website A.

And these different pages in website B uses sessions.

The problem here is if i access webiste B pages from the iframe of website A the session comes null and it throws many error.

But if i access website B directly in the browser everything works smooth.

So could someone help me with this issue.

-Dharmen

Comment: I'd be surprised if this was due to differing framework versions... why are you running the nav as a separate application in comparison to the content?    Which app establishes the session?  I very much doubt app1 and app2 could share a session... but i don't know i've never heard of anything like this :O

Comment: Kritner - webiste A just not do navigation of website B pages but also lot more other website pages. But this is just a part on which i am working. To answer your question website B Page A established session and website b Page B try to get the session stored by page A. And that time sesssion comes null and its not stored. If i do same thing without naviation from webiste A its works fine.